# How to extend face along its natural direction?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, workflow

How do you extend a face, or extrude an edge tangent to it?

In Fusion 360, [this operation](https://youtu.be/-IFFwiYmcWI?t=63) is called "extend - natural," or "tangent."

In Blender, the only way I can think of, is to select the faces in question, extrude them along their normals - which creates faces perpendicular to their original normal - and then again extrude the newly created perpendicular faces.
Finally, a lot of cleanup is necessary.

Surely there is an easier way, surely?